# CS-Script and Entity Framework

Tags: cs-script

I am editing an open source application to change the database accessing (SQLite) from a single user application to a multi-user application and I have employed Entity Framework and Linq to achieve this.

My problem is that this is a very large application that uses cs-scripting to get data from the internet and populates the database and I have never used cs-scripting before. Now that I've changed the database access to use Linq and EF the scripts have stopped working with the following error:

error CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I have put the following in the script:

//css_reference "EntityFramework.dll";

using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;

but the error won't go away.

This very frustrating because it is the only thing that isn't working and the application works as a multi-user system like a dream.

I must be missing something, but I have no idea what?

Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I've only gone and done it again.

The code I put in did work. I'd forgotten to copy the script to the target directory so it was running against the old script. Doh!

All working now (I hope):)

Tony